# Chrome Web App extension, minimize to task bar on window create

Tags: google-chrome-app

Anyone know how to get minimized to work, fullscreen functions as per examples on googles documentation

this with fullscreen permission in the manifest works

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('main.html', {state:"fullscreeen"});
})
```

However with state as minimized it just creates a 500px wide window and does not minimize to taskbar. I tried with minimized listed in manifest permissions but this did not appear to work.

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('main.html', {state:"minimized"});
})
```

Would be nice that user don't have to minimize my extension that runs to provide serial connection for hardware to website.

Comment: **Extensions** can't use chrome.app.window so you have a **chrome app**.

Comment: The problem sounds like a bug in Chrome. Try minimizing the window in the callback: chrome.app.window.create('main.html', w => w.minimize()); See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/app_window/#type-AppWindow).